# Why this shows runtime error?

Tags: c++, c

I was coding to create a my own `scanf` type function, when this problem occurred. The below code works perfectly when it is tested in the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

inline void fastint(int &x){
    register int c = getchar();
    x = 0;
    for(; ((c<48 || c>57) && c != '-'); c = getchar());
        for(; c>47 && c<58 ; c = getchar()){
            x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;
        }
}

inline void faststring(char * arr){
    register char c = getchar();
    register int i = 0;
    while (c < 33)
        c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n'){
        arr[i] = c;
        c = getchar();
        i = i + 1;

    }
        arr[i] = '\0';
}

int main(){
    int i;
    char * arr = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    fastint(i);
    printf("number is %d\n",i);
//  fprintf(stderr, "new format %d\n", that_pesky_x);
        fastint(i);
    printf("number is %d\n",i);
        fastint(i);
    printf("number is %d\n",i);
        fastint(i);
    printf("number is %d\n",i);
        fastint(i);
    printf("number is %d\n",i);

    faststring(arr);
    printf("string is %c\n",arr[3]);

        faststring(arr);
    printf("string is %c\n",arr[3]);

        faststring(arr);
    printf("string is %c\n",arr[3]);
        faststring(arr);
    printf("string is %s\n",arr);
        faststring(arr);
    printf("string is %s\n",arr);
        faststring(arr);
    printf("string is %s\n",arr);

    return 0;
}
```

But when the above code is tested on a text file(named input.txt) whose contents are:

```
12
32
12
42
343
hello dear
how is life
it is good man
Yes, it is the one
Have been search for this
Really, it is the only one
```

and trying to save the output to another text file(output.txt) using the windows command
`new_scan.exe <input.txt> output.txt`
in windows it is showing `new_scan.exe has stopped working`.

Possibly this is due to segmentation fault but I could not figure it out. Please help to resolve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I do that always before posting questions here.

Comment: Then you are using it the wrong way. Even executing this code block line by line and inspecting the results will solve your problem easily.

Comment: IF you actually did any debugging, YOU SHOULD HAVE LISTED WHAT YOU FOUND OUT SO THAT WE DON'T HAVE TO ALL GO OVER THE SAME GROUND. TO NOT DO SO IS DISRESPECTFUL OF THE TIME AND EFFORT THAT SO CONTRIBUTORS PUT IN.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is either a liar or is dissing SO contributors by not listing the results of debugging already one.

Comment: @MartinJames Really? Not trying to offend anyone but what do you want from me? Do you want me to list the results of each and every debugging I have done and then make this post even longer? 
It is highly implicative from the given lines 
1) "But when the above code is tested on a text file(named input.txt) whose contents are: "
2) "it is showing new_scan.exe has stopped working."
3) "Possibly this is due to segmentation fault but I could not figure it out."
And the most important thing to know about me is that I NEVER LIE. So I request you not to accuse anyone before knowing him or her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to increase your array size because some of your test cases are more than 20 bytes.

Second since you are reading from a file so you need to check for EOF.
So change

```
while (c != '\n'){
//  Do some work
}
```

To

```
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF){
// Do some work.
}
```

Lastly, you need to free your allocated memory  for good practices.

Now your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your array size is `20` bytes but few sentences in the text file are more than `20` characters (bytes) in length.

Accessing the unallocated memory might be causing SEG-Fault.

Another issue that can be there, is the end of line delimiter. You have checked for `\n` as EOL, but it can be of the form `\r\n` (CR-LF combination). So You shoul check for `\r` also as the delimiter.

Also, a suggestion for you, You must `free` the memory you allocate using `'alloc` family of functions.

Comment: Ok, but even if I change it to 200 bytes, it shows the same "...exe stopped working". SO how resolve this issue ?

Comment: @user3606997 : I have updated the answer with another possible problem and its solution.